# Can't get Font-Awesome icons in Semantic-UI build

Tags: build, gulp, icons, font-awesome, semantic-ui

I forked the Semantic-UI repository to make some custom changes.
After `gulp build` is launched and Semantic-UI run, the main issue I get is that I cannot see any icon.
If I compare the `dist` folder of original Semantic-UI and mine forked, I see that I do not have Font-Awesome icons in `icon.css` file:

[image]

I tried to debug the `build` guld task but it seems to be ok.
What could I do to figure out what is the cause of missing code?

Comment: See if you get a 404 error, that way you will know if the style is missing or just the font file. If there is no 404 error, then please provide more information.

Comment: I have no 404 errors. What infos could I provide more?